# How to set default layer group in Photoshop cs6 that i can call all the time for new psd files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I'm using a layer group all the time for my psd files. I would like to call/insert that group as a default layer group all the time into new psd. What is the best way to that? Currently i go to previous work and move it to new psd.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a document with that group and save it. When you want to make a new document, you just have to open that "template" file. You can then use ctrl+alt+c to resize the document.

Second option is to create an action and play that everytime you make a new document.

Comment: second option worked for me. Thank you so much.